# android grid view

Tags: android, gridview

i am developing one simple application for android mobile  here i am using two grid view i want to display one grid view in page load and other one is on click of first grid view row clcik how to do that
please help or give me code sample or link to refer

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create your layout with both views on and set the second one to invisible. Then in your activity you can set an onClick listener to the first GridView with something like:

```
GridView g = findViewById(R.id.second_grid_view);
g.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid view example is there in the API Demos. You can find it on 
[Android Grid View](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Grid2.html)

The necessary files are present in the API Demos present in your android setup.

Comment: if you want to launch a gridview on click of other's row. You can use the second gridview in an activity with dialog theme. This will thus be showed as a popup to the first gridView's onclick. You can set different such activities for each of the row of first gridview.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to launch a gridview on click of other's row. You can use the second gridview in an activity with dialog theme. This will thus be showed as a popup to the first gridView's onclick. You can set different such activities for each of the row of first gridview.